# ARM : What's the difference between APCS and AAPCS ABI?

Tags: arm

I'm currently porting a compiler written for ARM to another target architecture. I found there exists two different kinds of `ABI` for ARM: `APCS_ABI` and `AAPCS_ABI`.

I googled it and referenced the ARM manual, but haven't found the differences between them.

In the implementation of the compiler backend, however, the two kinds of `ABIs` are treated differently and have seperate implementations.

By the way, `APCS` is the abbreviation of ARM Procedure Call Standard, and `AAPCS` of Procedure Call Standard for the ARM Architecture. (Don't they mean the same thing ?)

So what's the difference between `APCS` and `AAPCS`? Why two different kinds of `ABIs` are defined?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From [ARM docs](https://github.com/ARM-software/abi-aa/releases/download/2022Q1/aapcs32.pdf),

> PCS  Procedure Call Standard.
>
> AAPCS  Procedure Call Standard for the
> ARM Architecture (this standard). (**current standard** )
>
> APCS  ARM Procedure Call Standard
> (**obsolete**).

Also, from the same doc,

> **The AAPCS embodies the fifth major revision of the APCS** and third
> major revision of the TPCS. It forms part of the complete ABI
> specification for the ARM Architecture.

So you can forget about the obsoleted `APCS` and start following `AAPCS`

Comment: The dcumentation link in this answer is now dead, and I haven't been able to find the current version yet, so here's an archive copy from roughly the same date as the answer: https://web.archive.org/web/20120424212439/http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042d/IHI0042D_aapcs.pdf **EDIT:** THis looks like the current version: https://github.com/ARM-software/abi-aa/releases/download/2022Q1/aapcs32.pdf

Comment: You're welcome! I try to fix links whenever I encounter a helpful answer with broken links, but the edit queue sometimes gets in the way.